# Datatable is receiving the date in (01\dd\yyyy) format from SQL query result in VB.NET application that I'm building for windows 10

Tags: vb.net, oracle11g

I'm new to VB.net and this forum. I'm porting the VB application to be compatible with windows 10. The datatable result is displaying the dates incorrectly the dates are displayed in the format of '01\dd\yyyy' the month is coming properly whereas the date and year are improper. I have attached the Dataset visualizer for your reference.

The same code is working properly in case of Windows 7 and it is not working for windows 10. Please let me know if any input is required from my end.

What I have tried:

I have tried changing the datatable to dataset but no luck.

```
Public Function GetIntegrationLogs( _
               ByVal FileType As String, _
               ByVal dtFrom As Date, _
              ByVal dtTo As Date) As DataTable

    Try
```

## If ORACLE Then

```
        Dim dtSC As New DataTable
        Dim adaptSC As New OracleDataAdapter

        'Dim myCommand As New OracleCommand("GetIntegrationLogs", deCCAS.Connection)
        'myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        'myCommand.Parameters.Add("v_FileType", FileType)
        'myCommand.Parameters.Add("v_StartDate", dtFrom)
        'myCommand.Parameters.Add("v_EndDate", dtTo)

        'reader = 

        Dim objCommand As New OracleCommand("GetIntegrationLogs", deCCAS.Connection)
        adaptSC.SelectCommand = objCommand
        Dim sysRefCursor As New OracleParameter
        With sysRefCursor
            .OracleDbType = OracleDbType.RefCursor
            .Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
        End With
        With objCommand
            .CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            .Parameters.Add("v_FileType", FileType)
            .Parameters.Add("v_StartDate", dtFrom)
            .Parameters.Add("v_EndDate", dtTo)
            .Parameters.Add(sysRefCursor)
        End With

        Dim da As OracleDataAdapter = New OracleDataAdapter(objCommand)
        adaptSC.Fill(dtSC)
```

[image of data visualizer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KG7Fb.png)

Comment: Please show your code, otherwise this question will be closed as lacking a proper [mcve]

Comment: As a side note, the display of DD/YYYY seems an hint to a improper masking format. Days are displayed with lowercase d and years with lowercase y

Comment: What are the datatype of the two columns containing the dates in the Oracle tables used by your Stored Proc? And when using parameters always specify the datatype of the parameter not just the value

Comment: Hi Steve, The datatype of the two columns is "Date"

Comment: It is not only about one procedure it is same with all the procedure and all the screens using them are displaying the date in DD\YYYY format. And with the same code if i debug the VB application in windows 7  I am able to see proper results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The windows 10 default date format was m\d\yyyy hence I was facing that incorrect date format. After changing the default date format of win10 OS now the issue is resolved.